# проблема в ajax

Tags: ajax, auth

почему так все норм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а так:

```
$.get( "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=ae2edcbd91e477796bf9", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

еще есть так:

```
<?php 
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/users/MACTEPwar');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        //echo $out;

        $result = file_get_contents('https://api.github.com/users/MACTEPwar');
    ?>
```

результат:

```
<div>
    <pre>
        <?php var_dump($out); ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax-запрос не отрабатывает из-за CORS-политики, не разрешающей запрос к https://github.com из http://localhost:1234. В ответе нет заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin, значение которого разрешала бы такой запрос.

Запрос из адресной строки броузера или тулзы, вроде postMan'a, отрабатывают успешно, т.к. они не cross-origin.

---

PS:
Запрос через cURL библиотеку работает, если добавить в запрос заголовок *User-Agent*:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/users/MACTEPwar');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36');
    var_dump(
        json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true)
    );
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: вопрос в том, почему с постмена проходит?

Comment: Потому, что, как я написал а ответе, это не cross-origin запрос и на него не распространяется СORS-политика.

Comment: хоро, что нужно сделать, чтобы запрос прошел? ведь с постмена ж как то проходит...

Comment: и еще момент...если я просто перейду по этой ссылке так : `<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=ae2edcbd91e477796bf9">Click here</a>` то все ок, я попадаю куда мне нужно (меня редиректит на страничку авторизации)

Comment: Установить расширение к броузеру. Например для хрома -  _Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *_ Только врядли это будет вариантом для вашей задачи. Но в **Вашем** броузере ajax-запрос точно заработает ))

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Ничего нового конешно не узнал, но нужно было удостовериться